# Find Path to Powershell in Nsis

Tags: windows, powershell, path, registry, nsis

I am using Powershell in a NSIS installer to run some scripts that needs to be executed. Most answers will tell to use something similar to this:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'powershell -inputformat none -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "file1.ps1"'
```

The problem with this solution is that it relies on the path variable in Windows. If Powershell isn't set in the path Powershell will never be executed.

Is there any better and more reliable way to make sure Powershell is executed even without the path variable being set?

The install path for Powershell is (as far as I know)
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Can this be used to reliably open Powershell without the path variable? Or can the path be read from the registry somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell path is included in the `PATH` environment variable by default, so using just the executable name should work unless someone deliberately removes the directory from the `PATH` variable. I would recommend to specify the extension, though.

The install path is relative to the Windows system directory, so if you want to use the full path, I'd use the `$SYSDIR` variable:

```
$SYSDIR\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```